# apex trigger (error :UpdateCaseCount: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: GC1040 External entry point)

Tags: apex

```
trigger UpdateCaseCount on Case(after insert, after update) {
    
    Set<Id> AccIdUpd = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Id> AccPrd = new Map<Id, Id>();
    set<id> ContactId = new set<id>();

    //Create a master list to hold the emails we'll send
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for (Case cs:Trigger.new) { 
        if(Trigger.IsInsert || (cs.IsClosed && Trigger.OldMap.get(cs.Id).IsClosed != cs.IsClosed)) {
            AccIdUpd.add(cs.AccountId);
            AccPrd.put(cs.AccountId, cs.Product__c);
        }
    }

    List<AggregateResult> ARListCurrIssue = [
        select AccountId, Product__c, Count(Id) CaseCount 
        from Case 
        where AccountId IN :AccIdUpd and IsClosed != true group by AccountId, Product__c
    ];

    // Logic to update curernt Issues
    List<Account> UpdAccList = new List<Account>();
    for (AggregateResult AR : ARListCurrIssue) {
        String CurrCount = AR.get('CaseCount') + ', ' +  AccPrd.get((Id) AR.get('Product__c'));
        UpdAccList.add(new Account(Id = (ID)AR.get('AccountId'), Current_Issues__c = CurrCount));
        Integer iCount = Integer.valueOf(AR.get('CaseCount'));
        if (iCount == 5) {
            //write logic to sendMail     

            Contact con = [Select firstname,lastname,email,id,name,MobilePhone from Contact where id in :ContactId];
            // Step 1: Create a new Email
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            // Step 2: Set list of people who should get the email
            List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
            sendTo.add(con.email);
            mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);

            // Step 3: Set who the email is sent from
            mail.setReplyTo('lateshpatil97@gmail.com');
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('latesh patil');

            // (Optional) Set list of people who should be CC'ed
            List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
            ccTo.add('lateshpatil@icloud.com');
            mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);

            // Step 4. Set email contents - you can use variables
            mail.setSubject('Get in touch with the service team');
            String body = 'Dear ' + con.FirstName;
    
            mail.setHtmlBody(body);

            // Step 5. Add your email to the master list
            mails.add(mail);
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
        }
    }

    if(UpdAccList.size()>0){
        update UpdAccList;
    }

    // Logic to update Past Issues
    ARListCurrIssue = [
        select AccountId, Count(Id) CaseCount  
        from Case 
        where AccountId In :AccIdUpd and IsClosed = True group By AccountId
    ];

    UpdAccList = new List<Account>();
    for(AggregateResult AR : ARListCurrIssue) {
        String PastCount = AR.get('CaseCount') + ', ' +  AccPrd.get((ID)AR.get('AccountId'));
        UpdAccList.add(new Account(Id = (ID)AR.get('AccountId'), Past_Issues__c = PastCount));
    }

    if (UpdAccList.size()>0) {
        update UpdAccList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more details about what you are trying to do and what issue you are facing?

Comment: can not be send a mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is failing at the following line:

```
String CurrCount = AR.get('CaseCount') + ', ' +  AccPrd.get((Id) AR.get('Product__c'));
```

You are using `AccPrd` map to store a mapping between `AccountId` => `Product__c`. On the above line of code, you are trying to retrieve entry from the `AccPrd` map using the value of `AR.get('Product__c')` which is incorrect. You should be using `AR.get('AccountId')`. Once you make that change, this error will go away.

There are other things which you might want to look into while writing triggers. I would recommend you to please [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmpW2pcgUG0) for basic Apex pattern to use while writing triggers.